# Where to find/how to install `libclang-*.so.1` on CentOS?

Tags: centos, amazon-linux

I am trying to find a library of `libclang-*.so.1` on centOS, but didn't find it anywhere. I have already installed `clang` and `llvm-toolset-7.0`. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
# yum whatprovides *libclang.so
```

So it should tell you all packages with that file:

```
clang-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64 : A C language family front-end for LLVM
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/llvm/libclang.so



clang-3.4.2-9.el7.x86_64 : A C language family front-end for LLVM
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/llvm/libclang.so



llvm-private-7.0.1-1.el7.i686 : llvm engine for Mesa
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/clang-private/libclang.so



llvm-private-7.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 : llvm engine for Mesa
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/clang-private/libclang.so



llvm-private-7.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 : llvm engine for Mesa
Repo        : @base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/clang-private/libclang.so
```

Now, I'm not sure what exact version/library you are looking for, but with the `yum whatprovides` command you should be able to find it.